# Enable button when checkboxes selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple checkboxes and a submit button that is initially disabled. When checking a box the button is enabled and when unchecking, the button is disabled again.

If have multiple checkboxes selected but uncheck one, the button becomes disabled even though I have selected other checkboxes. How can I fix this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
      $(".delete").attr("disabled", !this.checked);
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="32" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="44" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="26" class="checkbox" />

<button type="submit" class="delete" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".checkbox").click(function(){
        $('.delete').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/3U364/

Comment: Perhaps you meant `input.checkbox`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this where I am basically checking if all the checkboxes are not checked then disable the button.

```
$(function() {
    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
      $(".delete").attr("disabled", !$(".checkbox:checked").length);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very elegant, although I think it acts not the way the OP wants. Maybe it should be more like `disabled = !$('.checkbox:checked').size()`? This way the submit will only be enabled when there is at least one checkbox checked.

Comment: Oh, I thgt the other way. Well I modified my answer thankx though.

Comment: I modified my answer can you guys please remove the down vote?

Comment: @CyberJunkie - Take a look at this answer its very simple.

Comment: @CyberJunkie - Can you accept this answer if you are satisfied?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, your js works great but AlienWebguy was quickest to post a similar js using the `prop()` method which to my knowledge is more consistent than `attr()`.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a counter to track how many are checked, rather than just disabling the button. Add 1 every time a box is checked, and subtract 1 every time a box is unchecked. Once the counter hits 0, disable the button. When it changes to 1, enable the button (if it changes to any higher number it will have already been enabled, so you don't need to enable it every time). Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var boxcounter;
$(function() {
    boxcounter = 0;
    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            counter++;
            if(counter == 1){
                $(".delete").attr("disabled", "");
            }
        } else {
            counter--;
            if(counter == 0){
                $(".delete").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks that's intuitive but I try to use the most compact solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the state of the other boxes each time 1 box is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of every checkbox.
Then, loop through testing for checked, and exit the loop on checked (this is what you care about).
If you reach the end of the loop and checked for all was false, then disable the button.

This will prevent one uncheck from disabling the button.

You're currently only checking "this" checkbox rather than all.

Answer (score 0):

This code is Actually works without any error.

```
var boxcounter;
$(function() {
    let boxcounter = 0;
    $(".cgv-checkbox").click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            console.log('checked');
            boxcounter++;
            if(boxcounter == 3){
                $("#register_form_Register").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        } else {
            boxcounter--;
            if(boxcounter < 3){
                $("#register_form_Register").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This will work with multiple checkboxes as well.