# disabling button upon checking more than one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having three rows  containing checkbox and play buttons of which first row is a global one(Play button is  disabled on document ready)
and remaining in this case two are normal ones now if i check more than one normal check boxes their respective play buttons must be disabled and the global play must be abled

[image]

Comment: What is your code you need help with? We have to see an attempt before we can help you.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287948/enable-button-when-checkboxes-selected?rq=1)
.Additional steps is you need to have a **count variable** and if this count var is **greater than 2** then change property to disabled and toggle first one's prop to enabled . It would be much helpful if you share the code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/q1vf8d4r/   i tried this (jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/q1vf8d4r ) and it would be really great if any suggests me how to disable the child buttons and enabling only the global button when the count is more than 2